# Display current close votes in close vote review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, vote-to-close

I think it would be beneficial to see the current votes on questions in the close vote review queue. And also be able to see which users chose to leave it open. It can be anonymous if that is a concern (but it's already showing when you already reviewed a question).

Every now and again I click on close **just** to see what votes were cast thus far when I need a nudge to make up my mind (whether this is good practice is probably arguable) (it's typically between closing or skip, or leave open or skip, *not between leave open and close*).

**Something like this:** (which is identical to what you see when you already reviewed a question, but with the reason added, which I see no reason not to add to that view as well)

[image]

I realize one of the comments would most likely be that this may turn into sort of a peer-pressure scenario - voting the same as everyone else. If this is a valid concern, my only thoughts currently is to have this display be a higher-reputation privilege (or unlocked once you've cast many close votes) (presumably users will then be able to make up their own mind).

Any comments?

**EDIT:**

Ok, maybe not the best idea, but **how about** being able to see the screen **after you've skipped the question**, so you can at least see what other people thought (without being able to vote on it then). So that, over time, you'll get a better idea of what should and shouldn't be closed.

I realise this will require a change in the way things work by disallowing voting after skipping a question (at least I think).

Comment: If you need to look at who's voted to close and who's voted to leave it open, you're doing it wrong. You should be deciding if it's close-worthy from the content alone, not from votes counts in the close dialog.

Comment: *"I click on close just to see what votes were cast thus far "* I do this all the time. Sometimes it's not totally clear and you have to really scrutinize the question. Seeing the current CVs helps tell you what to look for. Or for example if I see a couple "off topic" votes, I may raise my voice in disagreement in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that could very well be counter-productive; It could lend to people just 'piling on' close votes simply because they see someone already has them. You do get the count/types of close votes in the close interface, but that is after you have already made the decision to click on "Close" in the first place.

This leaves it more 'natural', and does not lead you too much toward closing. As it is, the post being in the Close Queue already might tend to encourage close voting, so I don't know if any more is needed.

Ultimately, you should be voting to close based entirely on your own perception. That said, it *can be* helpful early on to get an idea by looking at what other people did, but I think it might be best to go with actually closed questions for that - not ones that are not yet closed (because a couple people might tend to have a greater chance to be wrong than the full five)

Comment: +1 People "pile" votes without reading the post contents even now, without such a feature.